# Overlapping filament after increasing speeds Prusa Slicer

Tags: prusaslicer, speed

I'm trying to tweak my speeds to see what I can get out of my printer.

I have an Ender 3 v2 with dual Z steppers, E3D Hemera XS and Klipper with a 0.4 nozzle printing PETG Filament.

After changing the speeds I started getting this at the end of the lines:
[image: Faster Speed]

It is where the nozzle turns back for the next line. I'm trying to find out if there is a setting to fix this but I'm struggling with what to search for.

What would this be called and is there a settings that can change this?

Speeds:
Perimeters = 60 mm/s
Small perimeters = 15 mm/s
External perimeters = 50%
Infill = 80 mm/s
Solid infill = 40 mm/s
Top solid infill = 15 mm/s

Layer height = 0.2mm

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! What speeds are you printing? PETG is known for not being able to be printed really fast. Please update your question and post the speeds you use.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Oscar. Speeds added.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your [Pressure Advance](https://www.klipper3d.org/Pressure_Advance.html) might not be tuned correctly. At higher speeds, PA is practically a necessity. I found that [Ellis' PA Pattern](https://ellis3dp.com/Pressure_Linear_Advance_Tool/) is quite good for this purpose (it's also integrated into OrcaSlicer, if you use that).

Comment: I haven't got pressure advance configured yet. I'll take a look at the docs and Ellis' PA Pattern. Thanks.